# JWT verify signature

Tags: apex, crypto, jwt

I've got a jwt base64 encoded payload and a public certificate. I am able to decode the payload in apex but having hard time validating the signature. Its header has the algorithm RS256. How do I do this in APEX?

Comment: Have you tried using this library https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt/blob/master/JWT.apex

Comment: It helps to generate the payload by signing but not the other way round. My requirement is to decode and verify the signature.

Answer (score 3):

As of now the Apex Crypto Class doesn't support the verify method. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm

And most of the examples found are for CallOuts.